# Pandas cannot read file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, anaconda

When I tried to open the train set titanic problem from kaggle, filename: train.csv, it gives this error everytime, though I think I did input everything correctly (And I don't understand why it shows "\Titanic  rain.csv" in the error message instead of "\Titanic\train.csv" :

Error message: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File E:\Machine Learning\Kaggle\Titanic rain.csv does not exist: 'E:\Machine Learning\Kaggle\Titanic\train.csv'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams  #for figure resizing


df= pd.read_csv('E:\Machine Learning\Kaggle\Titanic\train.csv')
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Type 1:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Machine Learning\Kaggle\Titanic\train.csv')
df.head()
```

Type 2:

```
df = pd.read_csv('E:\\Machine Learning\\Kaggle\\Titanic\\train.csv')
df.head()
```

Comment: Type 2 shouldn't have the `r`

Comment: yes my bad, copy paste error, will change it

Answer (score 0):

Solved: it was because of the filename that starts with 't'. \t caused the error. I changed the filename and works fine now

Comment: @Nakhatra because \t is tab. See my answer, don't amend your filenames to suit, adjust how you use filepaths in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In python the backslash ''  is an escape character. So python doesn't like normal windows filepaths.

You can either add an 'r' to the beginning of your path to tell python to treat it as a 'raw string', r'E:...', or you can double them up wherever you use them in your path '\' or you can use forward slash instead '/'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash with a second backslash each time, like this:

`df = pd.read_csv('E:\\Machine Learning\\Kaggle\\Titanic\\train.csv')`

Otherwise, you could use a *raw* string by putting the letter `r` in front like this:

`df = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Machine Learning\Kaggle\Titanic\train.csv')`

The raw string just tells Python to ignore any special characters, like `\`